# How can I the full data in my json endpoint?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, rest, api-design, endpoint

I set up a simple json api endpoint for my Rails application. I have a model `Item` that belongs to another model `List`, and I want to display all the `Items` that belong to a particular `List`. However, only 606 `Items` are actually displayed before the json document abruptly ends. Is it possible to somehow specify that the endpoint display more data, or is that the limit?

```
def endpoint
  list = List.find_by(name: params[:list])
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html
    format.json {render json: list.items}
    # this list has thousands of items but only 606 are displayed.
  end
end
```

Here's the output in the server:

```
Called from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/activesupport-5.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:259:in `load_dependency'
  ActiveRecord::SchemaMigration Load (6.2ms)  SELECT "schema_migrations".* FROM "schema_migrations"
Processing by AdminsController#endpoint as JSON
  Parameters: {"list"=>"Double"}
  List Load (1.5ms)  SELECT  "lists".* FROM "lists" WHERE "lists"."name" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["name", "Double"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  Item Load (228.4ms)  SELECT "lists".* FROM "items" WHERE "items"."list_id" = $1  [["list_id", 34]]
Completed 200 OK in 5856ms (Views: 5215.1ms | ActiveRecord: 294.5ms)
```

Comment: How long does it take to output these 606 items? (perhaps, you can share the Rails log when this request was rendered)

Comment: @ZoranMajstorovic It takes 5856ms. I added the output in the server.

Comment: display where? on the browser? maybe it's the browser that's is truncating the response.

Comment: @TamerShlash Yes, in the browser. Browsers truncate content? I'm using Chrome, but I've never run into any truncated content before.

Comment: can you `curl -O tempfile http://localhost:3000/path/to/endpoint` and then check the file contents to see how many items are in the list?

Comment: Also, it would be helpful to to `puts list.items.length` and see in the console output how many items are in the collection.

Comment: 1. I don't think that it is a good idea to render all 606 items in one request. You should use will_paginate or kamaniri gem to make pagination work.
2. Have you tried List.includes(:items).find_by(params[:list]) or are you already doing eager load?

Comment: 3. Maybe its the browser limit for displaying the items ??

Comment: You say the output "abruptly ends"; is the JSON a complete, valid document, or does it just stop mid-stream (when viewed using curl per Tamer Shlash )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will reduce the time taking by query:

```
def endpoint
    list = List.includes(:items).find_by(name: params[:list]).as_json(includes: :items)

    respond_to do |format|
        format.html
        format.json {list}
    end
end
```

Hope this will work for you

Answer (score 1):

I have worked a REST API application and I have finished lots of things but not faced that type of issue, I'm writing the code below which way I have used to fetch data like below

```
def endpoint
    @list = List.find_by(name: params[:list])
    @list_items = @list.items.limit(100) #=> limit is how much you need, I have not so much data for testing like 10,000
    respond_to do |format|
        format.html
        format.json {@list_items}
    end

    # OR

    json_response(@list_items) #=> without respond_to block
end
```

Hope to help